# Rendering text with Header tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering, react-dom

I'm new to React and I'm experiencing a confusing situation.

I'm trying to render H1 tag using the ReactDOM but the closing tag of the header keeps on turning into a string.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> React Project</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello World</h1>,   
        document.getElementById("root")
        );

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code on SublimeText appears like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwhjy.png)

The error is [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<']

I tried using Constant as the [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) Official Website suggests,

```
ReactDOM.render(
                 const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
                document.getElementById("root")
                )
```

;

But the result is the same.

So What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also use a JS preprocessor to understand JSX format, like Babel

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render( 
    <h1> Hello World </h1>,   
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Ok Guys, thank you for your help .. Both answers resolved my issue but I have a warning displayed on the screen:

(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfnpidifppmenkapgihekkeednfoenal/vendor/browser-polyfill.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
antiphishing.js:16 Sending APH request...

When I went through the instructions on React Website [Add JSX to a Project], the instructions suggests I should use Node, I did the installation but the working remains.

Comment: @AbbasAlhashimi You can ignore the warning, and if you are starting out with react, you should go through this link. It removes all the configuration overheads like you just faced and you can focus on programming. https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Your `<script>` tag tells the browser it is `Javascript` but in fact it is JSX. You need to transpile the JSX with something like Babel. Try the instruction [you can find here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> React Project</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Hello World</h1>,   
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please read [this page to learn more](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).